# Posting data from a html form to SQL does not post

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I have a node.js web app, an SQL server, and I am working locally in visual studio code then syncing to azure.

I have a simple form on my home page which when I click post, should send the data to a table in my SQL database. However nothing is happening at all. I am redirected to the user page, and I get no errors, but I also get nothing in the console log, or anything posted to the table.

Here is what I have:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require("mysql");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var config = {
      host: '',
      user: '',
      password: '',
      database: '',
      port: 3306,
      ssl: true
    };

var connection = new mysql.createConnection(config);

app.use('/node_modules',  express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/Template/views/home.html',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('home.html',{'root': __dirname + '/views'});
})

app.get('/Template/views/about.html',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('about.html',{'root': __dirname + '/views'});
})

app.get('/Template/views/user.html',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('user.html',{'root':__dirname + '/views'})
})

app.post('/Template/views/user.html', function(req, res){   
  var fName = req.body.first_name;
  connection.query("INSERT INTO `Persons` (name) SET ?", fName.toString(), function(err, result) { function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
    res.send('user.html',{'root':__dirname + '/views'})
  });

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <title>Template</title>
      <link href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="/Template/views/user.html" name="formA">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"> <br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">        
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: remove extenstion in routes. `app.get('/Template/views/user', ...` Also I can see a bunch of errors in your callback to `query`, not sure if this is your actual code or some *copy paste* issue

Comment: The extensions in routes seem to be working fine. What are the other errors you can see? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try connection to the connection after defining it:

```
connection.connect();
```

then execute the query and finally close the connection with:

```
connection.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing those. I now get an error at least 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()'

Answer (score 0):

Add method='post' on your form.

```
<form action="/Template/views/user.html" method='post' name="formA">
```

And change the serverside code

```
app.get('/Template/views/user.html',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('user.html',{'root':__dirname + '/views'})
})
```

To:

```
app.post('/Template/views/user.html',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('user.html',{'root':__dirname + '/views'})
})
```

and start db connection like below.

```
var connection = new mysql.createConnection(config);
connection.connect();
```

Comment: When I add method='post', i get redirected to the correct address in the address bar, but the page just displays 'This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 405', but no error in the console.

Comment: I made the updates but I am still getting the same error. I'm not sure what is going on.